# Programmatically include layout in middle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

How can I programmatically include a layout in a specific spot in another layout?

For example, if I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, world!"
            />

        // INCLUDE HERE

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I include the following layout (programmatically) in that specific location in the parent layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/some_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add id to the vertical oriented linear layout (ex: master view). and the code for your dynamic view is below.

```
LinearLayout masterView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.masterView);

        LinearLayout childView = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        childView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        LinearLayout childToChildView = new LinearLayout(this);
        childToChildView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());//some integer number

        childToChildView.addView(imageView);

        childView.addView(childToChildView);

        masterView.addView(childView);
```